# Implement bidirectional full relation between two objects

Tags: java, relationship, java-17

I have 2 classes Mother and Child

Class Mother :

```
public class Mother {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Mother(int id, String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

Class NewBorn :

```
  public class NewBorn {
    
        private int id;
        private String c_daughter;
        private String s_son;
        private String name;
        private int birthdate;
        private int weight;
        private int height;
        private int motherId;
        public NewBorn(int id, String c_daughter, String s_son, String name, int birthdate, int weight, int height,int motherId) {
            this.id = id;
            this.c_daughter = c_daughter;
            this.s_son = s_son;
            this.name = name;
            this.birthdate = birthdate;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.height = height;
            this.motherId = motherId;
        }
```

Of course I have Constructor, setters-getters and to string

I find it not easy to understand this.
I do just need to  extend one class to another ? like  (extend Mother in the  NewBorn class?)
Can someone please explain how I can implement bidirectional full relation between two objects so further one I can say that (Mother may have many children, children has exactly one mother).

Comment: You're looking for composition, not inheritance : a mother has 0 to n children, while a child has a mother. That means having a list of children as a field on the mother's side, a mother as a field on the children's side, and the code to link them both at the time of the children's instantiation

Comment: Hello, So  whati  should have is   in class  `NewBorn` I should have this:  `private Mother mother`   and in class Mother  this : `private List<NewBorn> newBornList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Yes that's a good start :) Then you need to set those fields at the right time

Comment: By seting to the right time , what do you mean if you can please tell me ?

Comment: I don't remember myself, I think there are multiple good options. Try constructing instances of your classes then testing who the children of a mother are and who the mother of a children is. If you just define the fields you'll have empty list/null value, find which code is needed to fix that and where to put it in your classes (it can be done outside of the classes as a first step)

Comment: @Aaron actually, a mother has at least one child. This may hint at a general problem here, to model changeable state as an invariant of the class design. A woman can become a mother and a newborn won’t stay a newborn for the rest of its life. Once it is understood that these are just two states of a person, it should become obvious that it is misleading to have two different classes here…

Comment: @Holger you're right that a mother at least has one children, too late to fix my comment alas. I think you're reading a bit too much into it though, to me this looks like a standard introduction to OOP exercise

Comment: Hello ,  @Holger  is right ,  a mother can have many childrenand a child can have onl one mother   so : one-to-many relation between the mother and newBorn, but I cannot fugre out the code ....

Comment: @Aaron unfortunately, it’s very likely that you’re right. It’s a “standard introduction to OOP”, one of those teaching the wrong way right from the start.

Comment: @BirsanVictor think of `public class Person { Set<Person> children; Person mother, father; String name, gender; LocalDate birthdate; private int weight, height; }` as every person has a mother, even a mother has a mother. And the children may have children too, once they are old enough. Instead of `String gender;` you may use `Gender gender;` whereas `public enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE, OTHER }` but that might be an advanced topic. Generally, “mother” or “child” are *roles*, not classes, and can be established, e.g. by storing a reference to a person in the `mother` field or `children` set.

Answer (score 2):

To have a full bidirectional relationship, a simplest form should be represented like this:

Class `Mother`

```
class Mother {
  private Set<Child> children;

  // getters, setters, constructors, rest of props
}
```

Class `Child`

```
class Child {
  private Mother mother;

  // getters, setters, constructors, rest of props
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqi/index.html).